# Restrict client application for a specific trusted application within TEE

Tags: globalplatform, trusted-application, trusted-execution-environment

Is there a way to restrict client application to use a specific trusted application within TEE.
As far as the Global Platform specifications are concerned, any client application can interact with a trusted application using Global Platform client APIs.

My question is can this be restricted where the trusted application A, interacts only with client application A, and not with any other malicious client applications that wants to interact with it.